# UITableView grouped background color in iOS7?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I've been searching all around and I can't find it.

What is the UITableView grouped background color in `iOS7` in **RGB**?

Comment: Take a screenshot and look at the color in your favorite paint program.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you mean the grey color as seen here:

[image]

It's

**#EFEFF4** or **rgb(239, 239, 244)**

Answer (score 9):

Get the color programmatically with:

```
UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
```

This way you will always have the same color as the grouped table view - even if Apple change it slightly.